# Interface Builder's “Simulate Interface” is gone in xcode 4.6?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is it possible to 'simulate interface' in xcode 4.6? The command seems to be missing :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Xcode 5 and you can find this feature under Editor-> Simulate Document (not the Edit menu) as others have pointed out.

However, this feature is *only* available for Mac xibs and is *not* available for iOS xibs.

I am guessing this was probably the same situation in Xcode 4.6 back when the question was originally asked, hence the confusion in the other questions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible to 'simulate interface' in xcode 4.6? The command seems to be missing :-(*

It seems, NO

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 4.6, you can find from menu bar:

*Editor* (**NOT** *Edit*) menu >> *Simulate Document*

This one may be helped :)

Comment: I'm on 4.6.1, the Editor menu doesn't have such an option. I'm looking at a storyboard file, where you testing with a nib file open by any chance?

Comment: You can simulate Mac xibs, but not iOS xibs.