# control origin coordinates in interface builder are disabled in xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm a newbie to iOS development, and am trying to work through the projects in "Learning iOS Development."

When I drag a control, such as a button, to the grid in Interface Builder in XCode 4.6.2, I can specify numbers for the width and height in the Size Inspector, but not for the origin, which is grayed out. I CAN change the origin by choosing one of the nine points in a grid to the left of the text boxes for specifying the numbers, but this is too coarse-grained.

I've seen a similar problem reported, and the solution was to turn off Simulated User Interface Elements (see [Can't resize UIView in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087676/cant-resize-uiview-in-ib)). But I think this option has been removed from 4.6. (See [Interface Builder's “Simulate Interface” is gone in xcode 4.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623144/interface-builders-simulate-interface-is-gone-in-xcode-4-6).)

I suspect the solution is something simple that I'm overlooking. Any help is greatly appreciated!